# How to accurately measure 16MHz clock with Oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, clock, probe

I have a small problem trying to make a 16 MHz signal with a scope with 100 MHz 1 GS/s. I can't seem to be able to read the square wave from the MCU clock, see results on the attached picture.

I calibrated the probe with the 1 kHz built in square wave on the oscilloscope.

Also, I can see that if I output the clock signal with a prescaler of 5, i.e. a frequent of 3.2MHz  then I am able to read a signal that looks more like a square signal.

I'm not sure what I might be missing or doing wrong.

I'm using the STM Nucleo F410RB development board.

[image: measured signal in oscilloscope]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a schematic of what and where you are measuring. If you attach a probe to a crystal oscillator the scope probe capacitance will probably load it and change its frequency or stop it completely.

Comment: Search the scope manual for "counter"

Comment: That looks exactly how a 16 MHz square wave would look like, when there is no impedance matching and is probed with the long ground clip that can't handle the bandwidth required due to stray inductance. If the signal is a 3.3V square wave, then probe is set to 10x but scope is set to 1x so the reported amplitude is wrong by a factor of 10 too. Visually, the frequency seems to be close to 16 MHz as there are 4 periods in 250ns. What accuracy you expect to see, better frequency measurement or better waveform?

Comment: What I expected to read was a better waveform.

Answer (score 3):

The shape of the waveform won't affect the fundamental frequency of a signal. However an oscilloscope is usually not the correct instrument to accurately measure frequency. It may only have an accuracy of 1% or so.

As @glen_geek points out in his answer some oscilloscopes do have counter/timers built into the instrument that can give high-accuracy (typically only for a single chanell) but the frequency displayed using the normal measurement facilities are usually only obtained after the signal is sampled and so will not be as accurate.

If you want to measure the frequency accurately and your scope does not have a built-in frequency counter you will need a frequency counter/timer such as [Keysight 53230A 350 MHz Universal Frequency Counter[1](https://www.keysight.com/en/pd-1893420-pn-53230a/350-mhz-universal-frequency-counter-timer-12-digits-s-20-ps?cc=US&lc=eng)

The wave shape distortion you see is almost certainly because of your probing technique. The probe should have an extremely short ground - a couple of inches is too long. Your oscilloscope probe accessories will probably contain some small springs that are used for this purpose.

[image]

To get the best waveform I don't use a probe and instead use coax wired directly to the signal. with very short connections.

If the source cannot drive a coax cable directly a 470 or 910 ohm resistor at the probe point can make an ad-hoc 10:1 or 20:1 attenuator with very good frequency response (up to a few GHz). Set the oscilloscope to 50 ohm input impedance if using this approach.

Comment: "The shape of the waveform won't affect the frequency of a signal." You probably mean the fundamental frequency. The shape of the waveform in time domain obviously affects also the frequency domain of the signal. I thought this might be a little misleading, especially as a first sentence of the answer.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful information. I changed the tip to the one suggested, as I was using the sprung hook, reduced the length of the jumper wires and now I get a much better waveform.

Comment: _"an oscilloscope is not the correct instrument to accurately measure frequency. It may only have an accuracy of 1% or so"_ - Are you sure? The user manual of the entry-level Rigol DS1054Z mentions <25ppm accuracy for the time base. Of course the accuracy of the frequency counter depends how it is implemented (how many samples it considers, etc), and I found no claims for it in the user guide. But [this article](http://nerdralph.blogspot.com/2015/07/rigol-ds1054z-frequency-counter-accuracy.html) claims it observed <2ppm in practice. 1-2% sounds very pessimistic
 to me.

Comment: @marcelm - agreed if there is an internal frequency counter available that can give high-accuracy. Often the measurement in the scope will be derived from the sampled signal and so is subject to the sampling limitations and how many cycles are displayed across the screen. Depending upon the settings I've seen errors of worse than 1% even if the timebase accuracy if very good.

Answer (score 0):

Your oscilloscope photo indicates that you are able to measure the MCU clock at 16 MHz quite nicely.

You should be using a "10X" probe. It will add some capacitance to the MCU oscillator, which will likely shift its frequency lower. If the MCU oscillator has an **input** pin and an **output** pin, probe the **output** pin.

Your OWON oscilloscope has a time-base accuracy of \$\pm100\$ parts-per-million. If you need more accuracy, measure frequency with a **frequency counter** instead...a decent frequency counter should contain a more accurate time base.

Your OWON 'scope has an internal counter claiming 6-digit resolution. If this internal counter uses the main timebase (having accuracy of 0.01%) then its least-significant digits are suspect.

---

From the OWON SDS1102 manual:

**Counter:**
It  is  a  6-digit  single-channel  counter.  The counter can only  measure  the  frequency  of  the  triggering  channel.  The  frequency   range  is  from  2Hz  to  the  full  bandwidth.  Only  if  the measured channel is in Edge mode of Single trigger type, the counter can be enabled. The counter is  displayed at the bottom of the screen. Operation steps:

- 1.Push **Trigger  Menu**  button,  set  the  trigger  type  to  **Single**,  set  the  trigger  mode  to  **Edge**, select the signal source.
- 2.Push the **Acquire** button to show the right menu.
- 3.Select **Counter** as **ON** or **OFF** in the right menu.

Comment: How does this affect impedance mismatch of false ringing of signal waveform?

Answer (score 0):

@KevinWhite has given the correct solution.

Analysis. The underdamped square wave indicates peaks every 2/5 in 1cm at 50ns per cm=division approx. thus 40ns cycle = 25MHz resonance. This is common with long ground lead inductance 0.5~1nH/mm and special coax used in 10:1 probe < 90pF/m. The computed resonance is dependant on the length of the ground lead inductance. Thus to expect an increase in resonant frequency requires better impedance matching of the probe 10RC+L : 1RC ratio by reducing the L value. This raises resonant frequency by inverse square root (LC), so to raise 25MHz to 200Mhz 1:8 requires reducing the ground lead length by a factor of 64 down to ~5~10mm from (est. = ) 160~320mm supply or ground  lead length including probe ground  path length on cct board gnd location. So I predict your probe ground lead was too long and also calibration imperfect.

Conclusion: use ground pad or test points directly at IC.  Ensure Vdd,Vss is decoupled by at least 10nF directly at IC. As these also add path inductance to Zout.

Also consider CMOS output impedance ~ 50 Ohm +/-50% from RdsOn is also mismatched and further improvement can be made by examining all stray loads of breadboard wiring to output. (L,C)

P.s. 25MHz probe resonance is pretty common and this is another reason why all DSO’s have 20MHz LPF with amateur 10:1 probes.